# Socket writing java (android) to python

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I want to create a super basic Android App that connects to a python server running on my PC but the python server never gets the connection

my java code:

```
public class WriteToSocket {
Socket sock;

public void Test() {
    try {
        this.sock = new Socket("PCName", 9871);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unknown host: PCName");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No I/O");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void Test1(){
    try {
        this.sock.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No I/O");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

and

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    WriteToSocket a = new WriteToSocket();
    a.Test();

}
```

and my python server is

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
name = "PCName"
port = 9871

sock.bind((name,port))
sock.listen(1)
s,a = sock.accept()
```

I expected after the button click for the python server to accept the connection (I also tried changing "PCName" to "127.0.0.1")

I've looked around but nothing helped me so far :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your server socket to one of the IP addresses of your PC which is accessible from your android, and not to 127.0.0.1. Or alternatively bind it to all available interfaces (0.0.0.0).

Then connect from your android to that IP.

E.g. if your PC has IP address 1.2.3.4 then use this IP in both applications.

Use netstat to see if the port is really open on your PC.

Check to see if your android application has the permission to use the internet (specified in the manifest: "USES_INTERNET" or something like that).

Also your python script discards the connection as soon as it is made.

Comment: But it's not made, the whole point of this is to make sure I can connect both devices

Comment: Have you checked the steps mentioned above?

Comment: I did, after looking again an exception in the android app is caught but i've no idea on how to know which since it runs on an emulator

Comment: What has this to do with running it in an emulator? Check the stdout of your emulator. Or use `Toast` instead of `System.out.println`. Or log to your logcat and view it. Or use a debugger...

Comment: It throws IOException, I can't get the full exception message since when I try to log e.GetMessage() it logs "Permission Denied" for some reason

Comment: @Shay Do you have network access permission specified in your manifest?

Comment: I've added the permission a few mins ago and it works now, thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In python change bind address to `0.0.0.0`. It will bind for all IPs attached to your machine. Then in android app change to correct IP of your computer.

IP `127.0.0.1` is a [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) and you can't connect to it from outside of the system.

Answer (score -1):

The android phone doesn't know what PCName is, change "PCName" in the python code back to '127.0.0.1', then in the android project put in the local IP address of the server.

This of course assuming that both the phone and the server are on the same local network.

Comment: I changed the java to this.sock = new Socket("10.0.0.5", 9871); and the python to "127.0.0.1" And it still doesn't work (both on the same network)

Comment: hmm, are any of the exceptions being caught? If not are you sure the connection is not being made? You can try adding this right after sock.accept() in the python code

`print("Received connection from %s" % a)`

Comment: Actually now that I looked at the emulator an exception is caught but I have no idea how I can know which one since it's running on an emulator :S

Comment: When binding to the local loopback address on the python side, you will never be able to connect form your android.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I changed the local loopback to 0.0.0.0, now the problem is the exception being caught on the android app